# LUIS.ai json migrated to Rasa format json is not returning the entities but correct intent is returned

Tags: python, json, rasa-nlu

I have migrated the json downloaded from LUIS app to RASA format using command: **python -m rasa_nlu.train -c config_spacy.json**

My configuration file looks like this:

```
{     
"path" : "./models",   
"data" : "./data/examples/rasa/BookACab.json",
"pipeline" : ["nlp_spacy", "tokenizer_spacy", "intent_featurizer_spacy", 
              "ner_crf", "ner_synonyms", "intent_classifier_sklearn", 
              "ner_duckling"] 
}
```

A model was generated with json in RASA format as below. However, when I query this model using

> http://localhost:5000/parse?q=book a ride later

the correct high scoring intent relating to the text I entered and all its related entities are returned. But when I try another text like:

> http://localhost:5000/parse?q=I want to go ride today 5pm

The intent returned is correct one but it's Entities object is empty. As you can see below json,this utterance is also having entities mapped to it similar to the working example.

Please help me to know if this is an issue for everyone with RASA or am I doing any mistake? Thank You!

```
  {
  "rasa_nlu_data": {
    "common_examples": [
      {
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "RideTime",
            "value": "later",
            "start": 0,
            "end": 5
          }
        ],
        "intent": "None",
        "text": "later"
      },
      {
        "entities": [],
        "intent": "ServiceRequestEnquiry",
        "text": "wake up"
      },
      {
        "entities": [],
        "intent": "ConfirmationNo",
        "text": "no not now"
      },
      {
        "entities": [],
        "intent": "ConfirmationNo",
        "text": "not sure"
      },
      {
        "entities": [],
        "intent": "ConfirmationNo",
        "text": "no bot"
      },
      {
        "entities": [],
        "intent": "ConfirmationNo",
        "text": "no goride bot"
      },
      {
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "RideTime",
            "value": "later",
            "start": 12,
            "end": 17
          }
        ],
        "intent": "BookCab",
        "text": "book a ride later"
      },
      {
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "RideTime",
            "value": "now",
            "start": 21,
            "end": 24
          }
        ],
        "intent": "BookCab",
        "text": "i want go for a ride now"
      },
      {
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "RideTime",
            "value": "today",
            "start": 12,
            "end": 17
          }
        ],
        "intent": "BookCab",
        "text": "book a ride today"
      },
      {
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "RideTime",
            "value": "today 5pm",
            "start": 18,
            "end": 27
          }
        ],
        "intent": "BookCab",
        "text": "I want to go ride today 5pm"
      },
      {
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "RideTime",
            "value": "today",
            "start": 12,
            "end": 17
          }
        ],
        "intent": "BookCab",
        "text": "book a ride today 5pm"
      },
      {
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "RideTime",
            "value": "later",
            "start": 13,
            "end": 18
          }
        ],
        "intent": "BookCab",
        "text": "book shuttle later"
      },
      {
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "RideTime",
            "value": "now",
            "start": 15,
            "end": 18
          }
        ],
        "intent": "None",
        "text": "i want to book now"
      },
      {
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "RideTime",
            "value": "booknow",
            "start": 10,
            "end": 17
          }
        ],
        "intent": "None",
        "text": "i want to booknow"
      },
      {
        "entities": [
          {
            "entity": "RideTime",
            "value": "book later",
            "start": 10,
            "end": 20
          }
        ],
        "intent": "None",
        "text": "i want to book later"
      }
    ],
    "regex_features": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could include the [pipeline](http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html) you are using with Rasa. You can find this in your [configuration](http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) file. Assuming you haven't changed the default pipeline in `config_spacy.json` then you're using [ner_crf](http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#ner-crf) for entity recognition.

It's very likely that because of library differences Rasa just requires more training data than LUIS did. Qualitatively the `mitie` pipeline generally requires less training data, but the trade off is that it takes more time to train.

So the basic answer to your question is: **If you want to use ner_crf then you need to increase the amount of training data you are providing for entity recognition.**

That being said: is RideTime your only entity? If so you should look into adding [ner_duckling](http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#ner-duckling) to your pipeline, which can recognize dates. This would perform better than you trying to train dates by yourself.

So using your training data above and the pipeline:

```
["nlp_spacy", "tokenizer_spacy", "intent_featurizer_spacy", "ner_crf", "ner_synonyms",  "intent_classifier_sklearn", "ner_duckling"]
```

Here is the result:

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "additional_info": {
                "grain": "hour",
                "others": [
                    {
                        "grain": "hour",
                        "value": "2017-07-26T17:00:00.000Z"
                    }
                ],
                "value": "2017-07-26T17:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "end": 27,
            "entity": "time",
            "extractor": "ner_duckling",
            "start": 18,
            "text": "today 5pm",
            "value": "2017-07-26T17:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "intent": {
        "confidence": 0.5469262356494486,
        "name": "BookCab"
    },
    "intent_ranking": [
        {
            "confidence": 0.5469262356494486,
            "name": "BookCab"
        },
        {
            "confidence": 0.2812606328712321,
            "name": "None"
        },
        {
            "confidence": 0.08727531874740564,
            "name": "ConfirmationNo"
        },
        {
            "confidence": 0.0845378127319134,
            "name": "ServiceRequestEnquiry"
        }
    ],
    "text": "I want to go ride today 5pm"
}
```

This complete training set works quite well for me. It was just a matter of adding more training examples. So as you test more, if you come across an example that doesn't work as expected, add it to the training data and re-train. Thus teaching your model to handle more varied requests.

https://gist.github.com/wrathagom/7f05fbda75c785977bd07cd89e62ddd7

Comment: Hi Caleb Keller, thank you for your prompt and elaborate explanation. Adding "ner_duckling" did solve my problem with date and times but the issue still persists with utterances like "i want to booknow","later","wake up". They are neither returning correct intents nor respective entities. Is this happening with your model too which was based on my training data provided? How can I fix this..Please suggest.

Comment: I thought you said intents were working? I'll try to come up with a complete working training set, but as stated it just comes down to need more training data.

Comment: Actually they were working initially. This is the new behavior i observed now when I was about to mark your solution as answer. Thanks for all the help you are doing.

Comment: I added a gist link for a complete training set that works well for me.

Comment: Thank You. It's stable now.